# nfc option for NFS mount on Mavericks doesn't work

Tags: macos, mount, nfs

I have updated MacOSX to 10.9 (Mavericks). I want to mount NFS shares from a Linux server with the **nfc** option because I have filenames with non-ASCII characters. But when I mount the network share it seems nfc is not working:

```
$ sudo mount -t nfs -o resvport,async,nfc 192.168.1.12:/media/disk1/downloads /Users/me/download/
$ mount | grep downloads
192.168.1.12:/media/disk1/downloads on /Users/me/download (nfs, asynchronous)
```

And the character issue (accents, ñ...) is there: they are shown as ??

Answer (score 3):

Very late answer, but you should add nfc to `/etc/nfs.conf`

`nfs.client.mount.options=nfc`

`man mount_nfs` for details of the options.